# Isosceles triangle between two perpendicular line and a given fixed straight line

Tags: geometry, area

Lines $ax^2+2hxy-ay^2=0$ and $5x+12y=13$ forms isosceles triangle, find the area of the triangle.

My approach is as follow. Lines 
$ax^2+2hxy-ay^2=0$ represent two perpendicular lines viz y=mx and y=-x/m when these lines intersect 5x+12y=13 we get coordinates as $(\frac{13}{5+12m},\frac{13m}{5+12m})$ and 
$(\frac{13m}{5m-12},\frac{-13}{5m-12})$. After this i am not able to approach

Comment: Why the $y=mx$ and $y=-x/m$?

Comment: the third vertex is the intersection of the two perpendicular lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $5x+12y=13$ must be perpendicular to one of the angle bisectors of the lines $mx-y=0$ and $x+my=0$. Those angle bisectors have equations $(mx-y)\pm(x+my)=0$, so you must have either $5(m+1)+12(m-1)=0$ or $5(m-1)-12(m+1)=0$. You really only need to solve one of these equations, since the other gives the slope of the other of the pair of unknown perpendicular lines.

There’s a much simpler way to solve this problem, though. As you can verify for yourself, the unknown lines intersect at the origin, so the origin, the foot of the altitude from the origin and either remaining vertex of the triangle form an isosceles right triangle with area equal to half of the area you’re trying to compute. Letting $h$ equal the height of that altitude, this means that the area of the large triangle is equal to $2\left(\frac12h^2\right)=h^2$. This height $h$, however, is equal to the distance of the line $5x+12y=13$ from the origin, therefore the area of the triangle is equal to $$\left(13\over\sqrt{5^2+12^2}\right)^2=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have got the equations correct, the two perpendicular lines will intersect at the origin. Then, equate the distance from the origin to the two points you obtained: $$\left( \frac{13}{5+12m} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{13m}{5+12m}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{13m}{5m-12}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{-13}{5m-12}\right)^2$$